# Subtraction between two nodes

Tags: java, list, oop

i've to do write a code to solve this problem:

-Do the subtraction between two nodes p and q, where the substraction p - q is the list that contains all the elements that appear in p and not in q, knowing that p and q are ordered lists.

I tried to write a code and i know that it can't work...can you help me please to solve this problem? thank you very much!

```
 class Node{
    public int elem;
    public Node next;

    public Node(int elem, Node next){
        this.elem = elem;
        this.next = next;
    }

}

 public class Main{
     public static Node diff(Node p, Node q){
            if( p.elem == q.elem )
                return diff(p.next, q.next);
            else if(p.elem < q.elem){
                return new Node (p.elem, diff(p.next, q.next));
            else
                return new Node(p.elem, diff(p.next, q.next));
        }
 public static void main(String[] args){
 //.......
 }
 }
```

Comment: From the code you posted, it looks like you can combine several `Node` objects to create a [linked list](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-linkedlist). So I think you mean that _p_ and _q_ are two ordered linked lists and the subtraction operation (p - q) results in a linked list that contains all the nodes in list _p_ that don't exist in list _q_. Do you agree?

Comment: @Abra exactly, sorry for my explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursion never ends, since each return statement in your recursion method calls itself, which will lead your code to a Stack Overflow.

To solve this, you should decompose the problem.

First of all, let's find the base cases.
These are the cases where the recursion ends, and there's two for your problem:

- If `p == null`, i.e. if the linked list contains no more items, then the work is done, there is nothing more to add to your result linked list.

```
if(p == null)
{
    return null;
}
```

- If `q == null`, then you should add all the remaining item in your linked list, i.e. the p node itself.

```
if(q == null) 
{
    return p;
}
```

There is 3 more possible cases, where recursion occurs:

- If `p.elem == q.elem` then the node should not be added, and we should go to the next node for each linked list. Since the list are ordered, there is no way this node could be useful later.

```
if(p.elem == q.elem)
{
    return diff(p.next, q.next);
}
```

- If `p.elem > q.elem` the node might be useful, but we do not know yet. The next nodes of the second linked list might be equals, so we just skip to the next node for the second linked list.

```
if (p.elem > q.elem) 
{
    return diff(p, q.next);
}
```

- There is only one case left, if `p.elem < q.elem`. This is it, we are sure that this node is absent from the second linked list, so we add a new node to our result.

```
return new Node(p.elem, diff(p.next, q);
```

Note that you do not need `else` statement in each case since there is a return in each of your cases.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you really much! Your explanation is perfect, it helped me a lot!!!